# jQuery UI .click() on dropped item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to jQuery (UI) and programmed my first DnD GUI, where I can drag an element from the left into the right cells. I append a trashcan to the dropped item. When I click on the dropped item, the trashcan shall toggle out and back in.

My problem now is, when I move the element from cell to cell, the click-Event gets called +1 times everytime I move it and I can't tell why...

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KWT86/1/

I guess the mistake must be somewhere in the drop Block

```
drop: function(event, ui){
        if(!($(ui.draggable).hasClass('clone'))){ // first element -> make Clone
            image = $(ui.draggable).clone().draggable({revert: true}).addClass('clone');
            image.addClass('fill-cell'); // change width to 100%

        } else { // no clone needed, just moving
            image = $(ui.draggable).draggable({
            containment:'#gui-container',
            revert:true,
            revertDuration: 0
        });
        }                                   
        $(image).on('click', function(){
            image.children(':last').slideToggle();
            alert('clicked');
        });

        $(this).append(image) // apend object to <td>
        image.append('<a href="blabla" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash trash">Delete Image</a>'); // append trashcan

        image.removeClass('ui-draggable-dragging');
    },
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixing it:

```
$(image).unbind('click').on('click', function(){
  image.children(':last').slideToggle();
  alert('clicked');
});
```

**.unbind('click')**